# Actual value of a subclassed str

Tags: python

How can I read the inputted value `"transform"` from the instance of this subclass?

```
class Str(str):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "mesh"

    def __str__(self):
        return "mesh"

string = Str("transform")
print(string)
# mesh
print(repr(string))
# mesh
```

Comment: What do you mean "actual" value? And how is the code you posted behaving any differently than how you would expect?

Comment: Are you using both Python 2 and Python 3? You have tagged both, which somewhat defeats the purpose of tagging a version.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I'm not exactly sure; as I said, the binding picks up the value passed to the class, "transform", even though I can't seem to find that value anywhere myself.

Comment: We can't help you very well without seeing the code from the binding then. Would you be able to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using Boost.Python to show us this behavior?

Comment: I haven't downvoted but you could've shown which code "gets the actual value". That would make the question answerable instead of relying on guessing what did happen.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I've clarified the question somewhat. The involvement of a binding was for context and not relevant to the solution I am looking for.

Comment: After your edits, I'm inclined to believe that the answer posted by @user2357112 is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Indeed it is, thanks @SilvioMayolo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot edit the value. You can retrieve it as a regular string with

```
str.__str__(string)
```

using the overridden `__str__` method directly.

The C++ binding is most likely reading the string through the Python C API, which goes directly to the underlying storage in the structure your object inherits from `str`, bypassing the methods you wrote.

As for what you should do, you should get out of this whole situation with subclassing `str` and overriding `__str__`. The right way to do that will depend on why you even got yourself into this situation in the first place.

Comment: For context, the original question involved passing this subclass to a Boost Python binding.

Answer (score 2):

C++-Functions use the internal string buffers, and probable won't call `__str__` or `__repr__`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about how you change a string's actual value, you don't. Strings are immutable. The string value itself is `self` but you can certainly obfuscate that, as you're trying to do. Still, you can always get to it with `str.__str__(string)`.

To make a "mutable" string (one thatpretends to have some other value than its initialized value), you must override more than just the `__str__` method. That only comes into play when the object is printed, used in interpolation via `%s` or the like, or when `str()` is explicitly called. Python is not inclined to constantly call `str()` on objects when they are putatively strings already.

To get some semblance of the behavior you want, you must also override all the methods that allow the string to participate in expressions, such as `__add__` and `__mul__`. To get the string to behave like "mesh" when you add it to another string, for example, override `__add__(self, other)` to return `"mesh" + other`.

Even that won't do it completely, because there are plenty of contexts that don't involve a special method, such as `getattr()` of an object or accessing `dict[key]`. These will use the string's original value, which, as already established, you can't change. You can of course redefine `getattr()` and `dict` to address these cases, but that way lies madness...

Comment: "Even that won't do it completely" - This is what I figured. My next question was going to be, "how do I override what comes out of `str.__str__(string)`" But it looks like I'm out of luck. Thanks @kindall

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to get the "real string". For example using ordinary Python:

```
>>> s = Str('transform')
>>> str.__str__(s)
'transform'

>>> super(Str, s).__str__()
'transform'
```

However it seems more likely that `Boost` actually uses a C-API function like [`PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize`](https://docs.python.org/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize) (or similar functions) that will also return the "original" string instead of going through your overridden `__str__` and/or `__repr__` methods.

Very likely there is no way to avoid that just by overriding `__str__` and `__repr__`. You have to check how the relevant Boost functions extract the string-representation (or which fallbacks they use if that's not possible). That way you can try to avoid the unwanted branches.

Comment: Thanks for this @MSiefert; I've excluded the notion of Boost from the original question for clarity, but this information is very useful to me nonetheless.